# Android Google Map API v2. How to load "My Places"?

Tags: android, kml, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I have many maps stored as **"my places"** that I would like to show in my android application dynamically.

Is there a way to load **"my places"** maps into a mapview? I searched the old threads and the way I found is to export the data into a KML file and then parse to show it as an overlay.

I think that there must be a better and a simpler way.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks